# How to size an absolute positioned image for different screens?

Tags: html, css

I have a floating banner that I want to display over 50% of the width of large screens and 100% of the width of small screens (mobile devices). It must be positioned at the bottom of the screen and not at the bottom of the content.

The image is sometimes very small (I think on retina displays).

How can I improve my code to display correctly on retina displays, large screens, and small mobile device screens?

In the .css

```
.banner-sticky {
bottom: -2.5px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
background: rgb(0, 0, 0) transparent;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
/* filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";*/
}

.advert-img {
width: 50%
height: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 380px) and (orientation: portrait) {
.advert-img {
width: 100%;
}
}
```

In the .html file

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
.
.
.
<div id="sticky" class="banner-sticky" style="position: fixed;">
  <a id="ad-link" href=' #' ><span id="banner-ad"><img src=' foo.jpg' class="advert-img" /></a>
</div>


'<a id="ad-link" href=' + this.landingUrl + ' ><span id="banner-ad"><img src=' + this.imgSrc + ' class="advert-img" /></a>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using media queries

for retina you can use `@media screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx)`

and for screen sizes you seem to be using already. Instead of `max-width` you can use `min-width`

If you want the image source to be different depending on the screen size you can use the `srcset` attribute. You can see its support here http://caniuse.com/srcset

And if you want a responsive page, you should think the css mobile first. Start by creating the default styles for a small screen, then add the queries for larger screens.

Comment: Thank you. What would the css be inside the retina display media query? I've never worked with retina and don't own a device to test.

Comment: Mobile first! Thanks that was helpful.

Comment: you would need to put non-retina height & width on the image. considering that the image you are using is @2x